# Hinting Bazel about the critical path for reduced build time

Tags: bazel

I have some test and build targets in my Bazel BUILD file that take longer to run than others, so they end up being part of the critical path and always become the long poles for the build/tests to finish while the CPU is almost idle.

I have a theory I could reduce the total build (wall) time by shifting these build targets/tests to start earlier. It would shift some other tests to "fill" the idle CPU time towards the end, resulting in better average resource utilization.

Is there a way I can provide hints to Bazel in the BUILD file about what the critical path is likely to be, so that Bazel can prioritize making progress on that path to avoid it being the long pole?

I have not been able to find much about this in docs.